# Unable to understand the following derivative example

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We have just started calculus at my school and i have some trouble with one of the questions. I was hoping someone could help me unders\tand certain events and hopefully what i'm mis\sin g. The following is the question and the answer as it is stated in my book.

diffrentiate $$\left(\sin x - x \cos x\right)/
\left(x\sin x + \cos x\right)$$

w.r.t x

$$\left(\left(x \sin x + \cos  x\right) * d/dx \left(\sin x - x\cos x\right) - \left(\sin x - x\cos x\right) d/dx\left(x \sin  x + \cos x\right)\right)
/\left(x\sin x + \cos x\right)^2$$

That much is understood, however the next line is where it gets strange

$$\left(\left(x\sin x + \cos x\right) * \left(\cos x - \cos x + x\sin x\right) - \left(\sin x - x\cos x\right) * \left(\sin x + x\cos x - \sin x\right)\right)/\left(x\sin x + \cos x\right)^2$$

In the second line, the part of $\left(\cos x - \cos x + \sin x\right)$ is not understood. I can understand that $\sin x$ evaluated to $\cos x, -x\cos x$ evaluated to $x\sin x$. Where did the extra $-\cos x$ come from?

Similarly in the second differentiation, where did the extra $\sin x$ come from?

Comment: LaTeX hint: Putting \ before trig functions makes them look pretty.  For example: \sin(x) looks like this: $\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $x\cos(x)$ needs to be evaluated by the product rule: $(d/dx)(x\cos(x)) = x*(d/dx)(\cos(x)) + (d/dx)(x)*\cos(x) = -x\sin(x) + \cos(x)$.